# Duplicating Stripe Objects in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, stripe-payments

I am working on a SaaS system and while writing it, I was thinking about why I am duplicating the Stripe objects in my app? Why not just depend on Stripe to maintain all of those records. For example I have the models:

- Customers
- Subscriptions
- Invoices
- Charges
- Payment Methods

Some of these (Customers, Subscriptions) are crucial to my app and must exist as they contain extra information about the object. Others, are just duplicates of the Stripe objects.

So my question is, in your architectures, why not just rely on API calls to Stripe to supply the app with data instead of depending on API calls and webhooks to maintain a consistent state between my app and Stripe?

I can think of a few ways to write this.

1. Create a model and store all fields in the DB. This is time consuming and very rigid (lots of webhooks to monitor and syncing to be done). On the flip side, almost all of the information I need is local and doesn't need an API call to work.
2. Create a model for all objects but only store a PK, a reference field to the corresponding Stripe object, and any "extra" data that is specific to my application. All data revolving Stripe would require an API call to retrieve.
3. Only create models for objects that perform logic in my app (Customer, Subscription) and load instances of children via API EG:

```
class Subscription
  def invoices
    Stripe::Invoices.list(subscription: self.stripe_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The big advantage to keeping some or all of this state on your end is that you don't need to make Stripe API requests to get the information, which makes fetching the information a lot faster.

Also, as your system and usage scales up, it won't be practical to make an API request to Stripe every time you need some of this info, as you'll start hitting [rate limits](https://stripe.com/docs/rate-limits).

Generally speaking it's best to strike a good balance between optimizing both the amount of data you store, the complexity of the logic you write to keep things in sync, and the number of API requests you make.  The specific balance often depends on the unique needs of your particular system/tech stack/business/etc.

Comment: Those are my thoughts. Right now, this is just a hobby project. Nothing major right now. My plan is to keep as as right now with full models for each Stripe object, but only storing a subset of the data and falling back to the API if it isn't present.